# Django queryset exclude() with multiple related field clauses

Tags: django, django-orm

I am creating a sparse preferences table in Django.  My model is simple:

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='preferences')
    preference = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    value = models.BooleanField()
```

Some preferences have default states, so I need to be able to ask the database two questions: "Which users have this preference set to a certain value?" and "Which users do not have this preference set to that value (either because they do not have the preference set or because they have proactively set the preference to another value)?"

My problem is that the former question works, but the latter question (the same query clauses, but with an `exclude()` instead of a `filter()`) does not work.  For instance:

My test database has 14 users, and a single user has two preferences set: `'PREF_A'` is set to `True` and `'PREF_B'` is set to `False`.

```
>>> User.objects.all().count()
14
>>> User.objects.filter(preferences__preference="PREF_A", preferences__value=True).count()
1
>>> User.objects.exclude(preferences__preference="PREF_A", preferences__value=True).count()
13
>>> User.objects.filter(preferences__preference="PREF_A", preferences__value=False).count()
0
>>> User.objects.exclude(preferences__preference="PREF_A", preferences__value=False).count()
13
```

So, my results say that:

There are 14 users in total

- 1 user has PREF_A set to True
- 13 users do not have PREF_A set to True
- 0 users have PREF_A set to False
- 13 users do not have PREF_A set to False  **<--- this is inaccurate**

Where is this query going wrong, and how can I write the query to properly exclude people who have a specific preference set to a specific value?

I have tried using `Q` and `~Q` to see if the behavior would be different, but the results were the same.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a still-present gotcha in Django, where `exclude()` is not acting as the reverse of `filter()`. Here's [the documentation explaining the difference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships):

> ## Note
>
> The behavior of `filter()` for queries that span multi-value
> relationships, as described above, is not implemented equivalently for
> `exclude()`. Instead, the conditions in a single `exclude()` call will not
> necessarily refer to the same item.
>
> For example, the following query would exclude blogs that contain both
> entries with “Lennon” in the headline and entries published in 2008:
>
> ```
> Blog.objects.exclude(
>     entry__headline__contains='Lennon',
>     entry__pub_date__year=2008,
> )
> ```
>
> However, unlike the behavior when using `filter()`, this will not limit
> blogs based on entries that satisfy both conditions. In order to do
> that, i.e. to select all blogs that do not contain entries published
> with “Lennon” that were published in 2008, you need to make two
> queries:
>
> ```
> Blog.objects.exclude(
>     entry__in=Entry.objects.filter(
>         headline__contains='Lennon',
>         pub_date__year=2008,
>     ),
> )
> ```

What you've done is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thx, this answer is counter intuitive, but VERY important to know!

Comment: Oh man. How can I thank you? This would be my Xmas present :)

Answer (score 6):

I implemented a quick-and-dirty solution so I could move on, expecting it to be horribly inefficient; however, on inspection of the SQL generated, it turned out to not be that bad:

```
>>> User.objects.exclude(id__in=User.objects.filter(preferences__preference="PREF_A", preferences__value=True))
```

I thought that the ORM would load the results of the subordinate query into the webserver's memory before completing (this is a problem because our production app will have in the millions of users), but in fact it properly uses a subquery:

```
>>> User.objects.exclude(id__in=User.objects.filter(preferences__preference="PREF_A", preferences__value=True)).values('id').query.sql_with_params()
(u'SELECT "sgauth_user"."id" FROM "sgauth_user" WHERE NOT ("sgauth_user"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "sgauth_user" U0 INNER JOIN "feeds_preference" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."user_id") WHERE (U1."preference" = %s  AND U1."value" = %s )))', ('PREF_A', True))
```

I'm putting this up as one possible answer, but I am still interested if there is a way to do it with the straightforward exclude clause, or a way of generating a query through the ORM that works with straightforward joins and no subquery whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new django SubQuery to avoid doing 2 queries to the server:

```
User.objects.exclude(id__in=SubQuery(User.objects.filter(preferences__preference="PREF_A", preferences__value=True)))
```

Comment: The ORM automatically does this without `SubQuery` - check the OP's answer.